# Is there difference in meaning between these three sentences?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, comparison

Is there difference in meaning between these three sentences?

> He was working less hard than **it's usual**.
>
> He was working less hard than **usual**.
>
> He was working less hard than **usually**.

Comment: Since the statement context is negative, it would be better to use a negative verb. "He wasn't working as hard as usual."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He was working less hard than it's usual.

This sentence is grammatically incorrect, however it's very close to "He was working less hard than is usual." In this sentence the subject was working less hard compared to some sort of standard. This standard is usually seen some sort of prepositional phrase such as "He was working less hard than is usual for a bodybuilder."

> He was working less hard than usual.

This means that the subject was working less hard compared to how hard the subject normally works.

> He was working less hard than usually.

This is also grammatically incorrect, but it can mean the same thing as the second sentence if you revise it to "He was working less hard than he usually does."

Comment: What if there was a to-infinitive in the first sentence? "He was working less hard than it's usual to work"?

Comment: You might explain why the first and third examples are incorrect, rather than just correcting them.

Comment: @F0rg1v3n Yes, if you added a to-infinitive like in "He was working less hard than it's usual to work" it would be correct, but it would be very wordy, so you likely wouldn't hear a native speaker say that. The reason that this becomes correct after you add the to-infinitive is because the "it" acts as a _cataphoric_ it which means that it refers to something later in the sentence, rather than before. Often this "it" comes up in general statements and observations for example "It's good to eat vegetables" or "It's nice that you help your brother." Without the infinitive the "it" is extraneous.